# ASP.Net Core Web API works on IIS Express, but not working when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm new to ASP.Net Core. I have an ASP.Net Core Web API project through which you can connect to a local MS SQL database and perform CRUD operations for the database. The Web API works just fine when running on IIS Express -- it launches the Chrome browser, retrieves records from the local SQL database, and displays the values on the Chrome browser. But the problem is, the Web API does NOT work when deployed to IIS (that is, when published to a folder and being run on IIS.)

I guess the problem is about connecting to the MS SQL database. I'm suspecting that connecting to the database works fine on IIS Express, but fails to connect when deployed to IIS for some reasons. But I'm not sure. The following is the connection string:

```
// Connection String=> "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=mynotedb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

    services.AddDbContext<mynotedbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=mynotedb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"));
}
```

I have an identical SQL database copied on my Azure account, and the web API works just fine for the Azure SQL database. It works fine both when run on IIS Express and deployed to IIS when it connects to the Azure database. For the Azure SQL database, the connection string is as the following:

```
services.AddDbContext<mynotedbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=tcp:mynote1.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mynotedb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=mylogin;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"));
```

Please help me with this issue. I've been trying to find the solution for the whole day with no success. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try to add application pool identity to access db?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov what is application pool identity and how do you add it?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov On my IIS Manager, I see 'Application Pools' tab. For the site for my web API project, it shows the status as "Started."

Comment: You’re using Integrated Security, so probably the application pool does not have access to the database. You can change the application pool identity in the IIS configuration (in the extended options iirc).

Comment: @poke Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Too many fundamental differences https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

first step check database connection work currently and TrustServerCertificate=**True**
next step check permission folders on your **host or your service provider**

Comment: I changed it to "TrustServerCertificate=True" but it still doesn't work. How do you check permission on the published folder on my host or my service provider?

Comment: your host should support dotnet core3, you sure this installed?